# iOS App Submission without IAP

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I'm in the process of making an iOS app. This will be my first iOS app. It is based on making phone calls using calling cards. The customer will buy the calling cards in the real world and they will get a pin which they would need to enter in the app. Through this pin they will get the credit to make the calls.
I went through the submission guidelines. Usually when a app requires the user to buy something from with-in the app, then IAP is used but here the purchase is being made in the real world, without using the app. Do I need to integrate IAP into the app? Will Apple accept the app into the app store?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's 'wlt`? What do Apple's guidelines tell you?

Comment: Sorry It was a type. I edited it now. From what I got from the guidelines was that any sort of purchase being made within the app needs to go through the in app purchases. However since in this scenario, the user will buy a physical card, then no purchase is being made inside the app. But I'm not sure how Apple would feel about an app like this.

Answer (score 0):

As your requirement suggest

> The customer will buy the calling cards in the real world and they will get a pin which they would need to enter in the app. Through this pin they will get the credit to make the calls.

It means you are dealing with somewhat physical stuff like customer will buy the calling cards in the real world so at that time he/she must have to pay something for that. so there is no need to integrate IAP in this scenario.

IAP is only for the stuff/service that will provide within the app by service provider. for physical service you can exclude the IAP. if you give proper description and explanation to apple when you submit your app for the review apple will definitely approve it

hope above answer will help you

Comment: If you'd give users game credit with physical cards, it's clear that Apple would not allow this. What counts is where the credit is consumed. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45380603/1971013).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're in a grey area because it all depends if Apple thinks the credit is consumed in the app. If considered consumed in the app, you may have a problem. Try to find another iOS telephony app that uses cards, one that's well know enough to be sure that Apple may have had a good look.

If you'd give users game credit with physical cards, it's clear that Apple would not allow this.

What makes this a grey area is the telephony side: If it's a VoIP app you could argue that the the credit is (partly) consumed while using the app. But you could also argue it's outside the app on the VoIP/telephony network.

If it's not a massive investment, I'd try the calling card route first.

You could try ask Apple, but you'll probably won't get a clear answer as they want to see the app first. I've tried this a few times in the past. Makes sense because they don't want to make promised based on what you write in an email.

Comment: Is there a limit to how many times you can re-submit the app for review after it gets rejected? Also all of the calls will be handled by a call-switch. The app will just trigger the web service to make the call through that switch. And in response to what @Maddyヅヅ said. After reading the purchase guidelines I also read that if a service such as physical goods is offered outside the app then you don't need to use IAP. Wouldn't the cards in this case fall under physical goods?

Comment: There's no limit. But of course you can get trouble if you're not reasonable or just plain annoying, for example if you're submitting the app with same issue (that Apple pointed out) over and over again. But if you for example would submit an app update that's all okay every week or so; should not be an issue. Apple is very reasonable, see them as nice people you want to work with in a good way; don't see them as nasty people that can reject your app for nothing.

Comment: I checked out some similar calling apps on the appstore. How do I know if they are using IAP or not for the purchases? Here are the links
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/calling-card-pal/id554111159?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cheap-calls-talk-more-for-less/id325041197?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nubefone-low-cost-international-and-local-calls/id642426762?mt=8